# How to pick the substring from a filename and load that substring into a table column in PySpark?

Tags: file, apache-spark, pyspark, substring, filenames

We are reading files from ADLS through this kind of command:

```
relative_path = "ContainerName/"
input_file_name = "ss_old_data_Amazon_Blast_202211093837474.csv"
```

How can we fetch a substring from a file name that we are getting for processing.

```
For example:
1st filename: vm_Path_Accenture_Complex_Union_202211027373.csv
2nd filename: vm_path_Google_is_a_good_company_20221109473.csv
3rd filename: ss_old_data_Amazon_Blast_202211093837474.csv
4th filename: ss_old_data_Black_Adam_(TY)_2022847093837474.csv
5th filename: ss_old_data_Man_of_steel_(PQ)_2022847093837474.csv
```

We need to pick specific substring from the filename and remove `_` from substring and make it upper case. I don't need to pick the date format (numbers) or `.csv` - just the company name.
`vm_path` will be there at the beginning for most of the files, and sometimes `ss_old_data`. We need to remove this part too.

```
Expected output:
1st filename should become: ACCENTURECOMPLEXUNION
2nd filename should become: GOOGLEISAGOODCOMPANY
3rd filename should become: AMAZONBLAST
4th filename should become : BLACKADAM
5th filename should become: MANOFSTEEL
```

How can we achieve it in PySpark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you store your file name in a variable, you can reuse it and save it as a literal (`lit`). But before saving you will have to do some modifications to the literal.

`ss_old_data_Amazon_Blast_202211093837474.csv` <- input
`_Amazon_Blast` <- after applying `regexp_extract` with pattern `'(?i)(vm_path|ss_old_data)(.+)_'`
`AmazonBlast` <- after applying `translate(..., '_', '')`
`AMAZONBLAST` <- after applying `upper`

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

input_file_name ="ss_old_data_Amazon_Blast_202211093837474.csv"

df = spark.read.csv(input_file_name)
df = df.withColumn('file_name', F.lit(input_file_name))

c = F.regexp_extract('file_name', '(?i)(vm_path|ss_old_data)([^(]+)(\(.+)?_', 2)
df = df.withColumn('file_name', F.upper(F.translate(c, '_', '')))
                   
df.show()
# +----------+-----------+
# |       _c0|  file_name|
# +----------+-----------+
# |csv_line_1|AMAZONBLAST|
# |csv_line_2|AMAZONBLAST|
# +----------+-----------+
```

Comment: hi @Zygd I saw some difference in my output, for some rare files we  have some values in the bracket at end when i am running the above code it is taking that bracket value also, which we dont want

Comment: I have edited the Question how the filenames are coming and how the output should look like, Sorry, i missed it at the first

Comment: i think of using Regex_Replace at first but thinking if values got changed inside the bracket value, it will not work, can't we have something to avoid the brackets and their values also if they are coming in filenames

Comment: Please try the updated version.

Answer (score 0):

One approach uses two chained calls to `str.replace`, followed by a call to `str.upper`:

```py
df["output"] = df["filename"].str.replace(r'^(?:vm_path|ss_old_data)_|_\d+\.csv$', '', regex=True, flags=re.I)
                             .str.replace('_', '', regex=False)
                             .str.upper()
```

Here is a regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/YTabgc/1) showing that the initial replacement logic is working.

Comment: @BigDataLover I am assuming that you have a Pandas data frame with a column called `filename`.